# Relationship between the conditional expectations of X conditioned on two values of Y.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am having hard time proving (or if it is even provable) whether the conditional expectation E(X|Y=y1)<E(X|Y=y2) if y1>y2. 0<=X<=1, 0<=Y<=1. Assuming that X and Y are continuous random variables and have a joint probability density function.

NB: So basically I want to know if I can do the following. \begin{equation*} 
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
&E[X|Y=y1]<E[X|Y=y2], \text{if}\ y1>y2\\
&\text{To see this, let us rewrite}\ 
E[X|Y=y1]<E[X|Y=y2]\ \text{as}\\
&=E[X|Y=y1]-E[X|Y=y2]<0\\
&=\int_0^1 X \cdot f(X|Y=y1)\;\mathrm{d}X - \int_0^1 X \cdot f(X|Y=y2)\;\mathrm{d}X <0\\
&= \int_0^1 X \cdot \tfrac{f(X,Y=y1)}{f(Y=y1)}\;\mathrm{d}X  - \int_0^1 X \cdot \tfrac{f(X,Y=y2)}{f(Y=y2)}\;\mathrm{d}X<0 \\
&\text {Since } y1>y2, \text{we can write}\ y1=y2+a, \text{where}\ a>0.\\
& \text{Thus, by substituting for}\ y1\ \text{in the above expression, we have }\\
&=\int_0^1 X\cdot \tfrac{f(X,Y=y2+a)}{f(Y=y2+a)}\;\mathrm{d}X  - \int_0^1 X\cdot\tfrac{f(X,Y=y2)}{f(Y=y2)}\;\mathrm{d}X  <0\\
&= \int_0^1 X\cdot \tfrac{f(X,Y=y2+a)}{f(Y=y2+a)}\;\mathrm{d}X < \int_0^1 X\cdot\tfrac{f(X,Y=y2)}{f(Y=y2)}\;\mathrm{d}X \\
&\text{and}\\ 
&E[X|Y=y1]<E[X|Y=y2]
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: If you could find such an example, intuitively, would you expect $X$ and $Y$ to be positively correlated, negatively correlated, or uncorrelated? (I'm not suggesting you can determine the correlation from the given info, however, the correlation concept may help to come up with examples).

Comment: @Michael, I would expect X and Y to be negatively correlated. An increase in Y decreases the expected value of X.

Comment: So then in negatively correlated cases the inequality might go one way, while in positively correlated cases the inequality might go the other way.  So you cannot conclude one inequality always works, can you?  Also, the case when $X$ and $Y$ are independent seems to be an important and easy case to try. I'm not sure what your precise question is, or what you are seeking, but these are things to try.  You can also get intuition by trying the case $X=Y$ and the case $X=1-Y$ (these latter cases do not produce a good joint PDF but you could add noise to get a joint PDF if you want).

Comment: @Michael, I have edited the original question and included what I am trying to prove.

Comment: Your manipulations seem to start and end with the same equation and hence they make no progress. They cannot make any progress, as you are trying to say an inequality is always true when clearly it is not.  Have you considered the case when $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. Uniform over $[0,1]$? Intuitively, independent means that the value of $Y$ does not affect $X$.

Comment: @Michael, I want a situation where the value of Y affects X (i.e., value of X depends on the value of Y).   Is it possible to prove this?

Comment: Did you ignore my prior comments on considering $Y=1-X$ and $Y=X$?

Comment: Let me try these cases then and see. Thank you.